# Upload multiple images to a database

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

I have the simple case where a user can upload multiple images for an item to the database. Can someone give an example definition of the model, controller and view? I can nowhere find a simple and decent example on this trivial case. I guess the model will look something like this I guess :

```
public class Item
{
    public List<byte[]> Images;
}
```

The View something like this

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("FileUpload", "Home", FormMethod.Post, 
                        new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{  
    <label for="file">Upload Image:</label> 
    <input type="file" name="file" id="file" multiple/> 
    <input type="submit" value="Upload" class="submit" /> 
}
```

Comment: Take a look at [this guide](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ABackToBasicsCaseStudyImplementingHTTPFileUploadWithASPNETMVCIncludingTestsAndMocks.aspx)

Comment: I can't find there what type my images should have in my model